# Clear Workspace before starting new test case

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am facing a problem in using eclipse rcptt, I have two independent test case.

The first test case create a new project in the workspace and do some thing and finally it delete the project from the workspace.

The second test case again create another project and do other thing.

The problem is when the first test case is failed, it can not delete the project from the workspace.

Before running the second test case I use

```
try{

    with [get-window "Delete project"] {
    get-button OK | click
    }
}-catch{

    with [get-window "Delete project"] {
    get-button OK | click
}
```

But it can not delete the project from the workspace. I don't know why??

For this reason, if a test case fail, than rcptt can not run the rest of the test cases.

Is there a smart way to delete project from workspace either test case fails or pass???

I have also tried by using the

```
empty workspace context.
```

The actual reason is given in the image
[image]

rcptt can not record this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to delete the project from ECL code.

Instead, use a Workspace-context in your test-case; it has a 'Clear workspace' checkbox which erases projects when deployed. It's deployed before the case starts; no matter how the previous case ended.

Comment: i have already mentioned in my question, i have used empty workspace context.

Comment: i have add an image.

Comment: Could you try first closing the project and then deleting it? Is it throwing the same error message when being closed?

Comment: if i use try catch than it can close the project though test case fails but the test case still pass as the test execution is finished successfully.